# How to split into valid array

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays

I've following object that is return from API and I want to convert them into array either in javascript or c#.

```
[
  "1":"h1:first",
  "2":".content a > img",
  "3":"#content div p"
]
```

I've tried converting that to json object, split function etc but din't working for me.

It throws exception `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` while using split function in javascript.

Comment: That isn't a valid structure to start with. Where is that generated?

Comment: what type is it?

Comment: Yes, I understand but what we can do with as Unfortunately I don't have control to change the API response.

Comment: Seems very strange an API would send that out. Is it part of a larger response? If it is sent as json it simply isn't valid json

Comment: yes, I think I've to convert that as per @rockstar's suggestions.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment what's wrong with the question? This seems to be valid question for me.

Comment: Refuse to use the said API and send them a bug ticket ;) Writing your code around a buggy API call is just asking for problems in the future

Comment: ha ha ha, sounds I'm stupid to ask this kind of question, that's not a valid reason! I was looking for a solution to my problem and there is nothing wrong in question,

Comment: I didn't down vote, I just happened to comment after you 've asked the question ;) (I upvoted the answer though I wouldn't use it, and would rather refuse the API call)

Comment: is the *object* a string?

Comment: Yes, object return as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose c# code to fix the issue instead client-side (as suggested by @rock star below).

```
string[] domSelectors = selectors.Replace("\"", "").Split(new string[] { "[", ",", "]" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var domSelector in domSelectors)
{
   string[] arrayElements = domSelector.Split(':');
   string selector = string.Join(":", arrayElements.Skip(1));
}
```

Hope it helps others who don't have control over API and want to fix the issue as I'd in my project!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert it to valid JSON by replacing the square brackets with curly braces.

```
var data = '["1":"h1:first","2":".content a > img","3":"#content div p"]';
var json = `{ ${data.trim().slice(1, -1)} }`;
```

Then `JSON.parse` it like you had tried earlier. And if you want an array, and don't care about the actual index numbers, you can use `Object.values` to get the Array of values.

```js
var data = '["1":"h1:first","2":".content a > img","3":"#content div p"]';
var json = `{ ${data.trim().slice(1, -1)} }`;

console.log(json);

var parsed = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(parsed);

var array = Object.values(parsed);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: @MayankModi: Yes, assuming those double quotes on the outside are not actually part of the string data.

Comment: Ok rock star, thanks for the answer and support. However, I've fixed the issue from server-side using c#.

Comment: Yes, for reference I've posted my method which might help others.